# Runtime error when using MPMediaPickerController in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mpmediapickercontroller

The following happens when I try to run an app using the `MPMediaPickerController` on the iOS Simulator.

```
2012-05-28 22:26:42.416 My App[48426:11f03] Could not load source: 3
2012-05-28 22:26:42.418 My App[48426:11f03] *** Assertion failure in -[MPMediaPickerController loadView], /SourceCache/MediaPlayer_Sim/MobileMusicPlayer-1391.72/SDK/MPMediaPickerController.m:86
2012-05-28 22:26:42.419 My App[48426:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to load iPodUI.framework'
```

Is this some problem in my App/Xcode/iOS Simulator, or does the iOS Simulator simply not support the `MPMediaPickerController`? If not, any alternatives, besides running it on a physical device?

Comment: This is now possible, see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MPMediaPickerController does not work in the Simulator. Apple notes this in the "[iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9)" under "Hello Music Player". The note says:

> Note: To follow these steps you’ll need a provisioned device because
>   the Simulator has no access to a device’s iPod library.

To prevent the assertion you can always check if you can access the do this in your code (code bellow uses ARC and iOS SDK 5.0).

```
MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems:YES];
[picker setPrompt:NSLocalizedString(@"Add songs to play","Prompt in media item picker")];

@try {
    [picker loadView]; // Will throw an exception in iOS simulator
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Oops!",@"Error title")
                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"The music library is not available.",@"Error message when MPMediaPickerController fails to load") 
                               delegate:nil 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if adding the try catch code is a requirement for apps to be successfully added to the app store? I don't intent to add this code if it is not a requirement.

Comment: While correct at the time, the current iOS Simulators allow rudimentary support for accessing the music library; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Also (if using storyboard) you can try it:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"playerTest"
                                                    message:@"Media picker didn't work in simulator, please run this app on device"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
#else
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowPickerViewSegue" sender:self];
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MPMediaPickerController` now works in the iOS Simulator without any additional code changes (at least as of iOS 8, possibly earlier). Here is a project that can demonstrate it: [GVMusicPlayerController](https://github.com/gangverk/GVMusicPlayerController).

You will have to prepare the music library in the Simulator by copying the necessary files from an actual device, most importantly the `MediaLibrary.sqlitedb` database files. If you want to play the files and view artwork, you'll also have to copy the `iTunes_Control/Music`, `Purchases` and `Artwork` folders (found in `/var/mobile/Media/`). See this question for further details: [Can i access iPod Library on simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3159716/381233).