# iphone: can you test accessing music library using simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i access iPod Library on simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159716/can-i-access-ipod-library-on-simulator)

I noticed that there is no iPod app in the iPhone Simulator.  If I am using the MediaPlayer framework and I want to test accessing the music library of the device (the simulator), can I do this using the simulator or do I need to buy an account so I can use my actual device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no access to the MPMediaPlayer framework on the simulator. You'll need to become a paid-up member of the Developer program and run your app on your device.

See also [Can i access iPod Library on simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159716/can-i-access-ipod-library-on-simulator)