# Access Xcode Simulator music with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, ios-simulator

I've implemented this mod [Can I add a music library to the Xcode iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300608/can-i-add-a-music-library-to-the-xcode-ios-simulator) to play music in the Xcode Simulator using the MediaPlayer Framework. This mod works great! My app can play the songs in a PlayList,
extract MetaData, and play songs.

I’ve recently switched the app from MPMediaPlayer to AVFoundation’s AVAudioPlayer.  It works great when Xcode side loading on a physical device, but fails in the Xcode Simulator.

I’m using MPMediaPickerController to select music.  I capture the MPMediaItem collection returned. I can extract MetaData from the current MPMediaItem, but get the following error when attempting to create an AVAudioPlayer with the MPMediaItem’s assetURL.

> ERROR instantiating AVAudioPlayer: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1768973119.)

Pertinent code:

```
let path: NSURL = item.assetURL as NSURL?
let avAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path as URL)
```

The MPMediaItem’s assetURL prints as

> Optional(ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=8845257749286139209)

The path: NSURL prints as

> pod-library://item/item.m4a?id=8845257749286139209

Has anyone gotten the AVFoundation player to play music in the Xcode Simulator?  (Again MediaPlayer player works fine.)